# How to use fluent api with a many to many table with three foreigner keys?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have these tables:

- TableA(IdA, ---)
- TableB(IdB, ---)
- TableC(IdC, ---)
- TableABC(IdFkA, IdFkB, IdFkC)

Also, I have 4 POCO objects:

```
TableA
{
    IDTableA;
}

TableB
{
    IDTableB;
}

TableC
{
    IDTableC;
}

TableABC
{
    IDTableA;
    IDTableB;
    IDTableC;
}
```

NOTE: I know I don't show the navigation properties, but it is just to say that I have the POCO entity of the realtion table too, that is not like when I have a many to many relationship with only two tables.

The TableABC has as key the three columns IdFkA, IdFkB, IdFkC. I would like to know how to map this with EF6 and fluent API.

I am thinking ins something like that:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TableABC>()
    .HasRequired<TableA>(s => s.TableA)
    .WithMany(s => s.TableABC)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.IdFkA);

    .HasRequired<TableB>(s => s.TableB)
    .WithMany(s => s.TableABC)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.IdFkB);

    .HasRequired<TableC>(s => s.TableC)
    .WithMany(s => s.TableABC)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.IdFkC);
```

How I have the relationship table, really it is a one to many relationship betwenn the tables, not really a many to many relationship, but I am not sure if this is correct.

So in sumary, I would like to know how to set the relationship between the three tables with fluent API.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know how to set the relationship between the three
>   tables with fluent API

I find it a bit unclear if you want a many-to-many relation between the tables or not. But as you mentioned "*really it is a one to many relationship betwenn the tables*" I assume you want it one-to-many.

The fact that you got 3 tables doesn't make it much different. You just have to do the same thing three times. Assume your models looks like this (but with public properties):

```
TableA
{
    int IDTableA { get; set; }
    ICollection<TableABC> Relations { get; set; } // Bad name but proves point.
}

TableB
{
    int IDTableB { get; set; }
    ICollection<TableABC> Relations { get; set; }
}

TableC
{
    int IDTableC { get; set; }
    ICollection<TableABC> Relations { get; set; }
}

TableABC
{
    int IDTableA { get; set; }
    TableA A { get; set; }
    int IDTableB { get; set; }
    TableA B { get; set; }
    int? IDTableC { get; set; } // Optional
    TableA C { get; set; }
}
```

I prefer to use [`EntityTypeConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696117(v=vs.113).aspx), which enabled you to use `this`. But otherwise you can use `modelBuilder.Entity<TableABC>()` instead. Then you can do like this:

```
public class TableABCMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<TableABC>
{
    public TableABCMap()
    {
        this.HasRequired(e => e.TableA)
            .WithMany(x => x.Relations)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.IDTableA);

        this.HasRequired(e => e.TableB)
            .WithMany(x => x.Relations)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.IDTableB);

        this.HasOptional(e => e.TableC)
            .WithMany(x => x.Relations)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.IDTableC);
    }
}
```

Note that all the mappings are based on the `TableABC`. You can just as well do it the other way around, but I personally prefer it this way.